# Why is this function only returning the first item in the list?

Tags: python, list, class

Class:

```
Person.py

class Person:

    def __init__(self, first, middle, last):
        self.firstName = first
        self.middle = middle
        self.lastName = last
        self.siblings = []

    def showSiblings(self):
        for x in self.siblings:
            return x

    def addSiblings(self, sibling):
        self.siblings.append(sibling)
```

When I add a few siblings to a new instance of the Person:

```
from classTest.Person import Person

newPerson = Person("Fred", "Baker", "Smith")

newPerson.addSiblings("Sibling1")
newPerson.addSiblings("Sibling2")
newPerson.addSiblings("Sibling3")
newPerson.addSiblings("Sibling4")
newPerson.addSiblings("Sibling5")
```

And then call the `showSiblings()` method.

I only get back the first member of the list.

Why is this?

Comment: Well, show siblings has basically that, you enter the for loop and return

Answer (score 1):

Change the class to

```py
Person.py

class Person:

    def __init__(self, first, middle, last):
        self.firstName = first
        self.middle = middle
        self.lastName = last
        self.siblings = []

    def showSiblings(self):
        return self.siblings

    def addSiblings(self, sibling):
        self.siblings.append(sibling)
```

And printing:

```py
for result in newPerson.showSiblings():
   print(result)
```